# How do I prove theta(log n)=o(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, clrs

I'm solving a question from CLRS where we need to prove that (ceil(lg lg n))! is polynomially bounded.

```
Let g(n)=(ceil(lg lg n))!

lg(g(n))=lg((ceil(lg lg n))!)
        =theta(ceil(lg lg n) * lg (ceil(lg lg n))) [since lg(n!)=theta(n * lg n)
                                                    and replacing n by ceil(lg lg n) here.]
        =theta((lg lg n) * (lg lg lg n))  ----(1)  [since ceil(n)=theta(n)
                                                    and replacing n by (lg lg n) here.]
```

**Now if I can prove that theta(lg n)=o(n)**

```
=>theta(lg lg lg n)=o(lg lg n)
=>theta((lg lg n) * (lg lg lg n))=o((lg lg n) * (lg lg n))
                                 =o((lg lg n)^2)
                                 =o(lg^2(lg n))
                                 =o(lg n)  ----(2) [Polylogarithmic functions grow slower than 
                                                    polynomial functions.
                                                    =>log^b(n)=o(n^a)
                                                    =>log^2(log n)=o(logn^1)
                                                    =>log^2(log n)=o(log n)]

From (1) and (2) we have log(g(n))=o(log n)
=>g(n)=o(n^a) that is g(n) is polynomially bounded.
```

The only problem I'm facing is to prove that **theta(lg n)=o(n)**.
Please help!

Comment: isn't it true by definition (of theta)?

Comment: Keep in mind that `O(.)` and `theta(.)` define sets of functions. You probably don't want to prove set equivalence, but that one set is a subset of the other.

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ Nico Schertler
Yes I want to prove that any function that is theta(log n) is also o(n). That hows the CLRS defines that equality right? Not by equivalence.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical CS. This should be moved to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To prove that `(ceil(lg lg n))!` is polynomially bounded, you can also use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).
Stirling says mainly `n!` is approximate something like `n^n`. So the following holds:

```
ceil(lg lg n)! < (1 + lg lg n)! 
               < (1 + lg lg n)^(1 + lg lg n) 
               = (1 + lg lg n) * (1 + lg lg n)^(lg lg n)
               < (1 + lg lg n) * (2 * lg lg n)^(lg lg n)
               < (1 + lg lg n) * (lg n) * (lg lg n)^(lg lg n)
```

Now it is only left to show `(lg lg n) ^ (lg lg n)` is polynomial bounded:

```
             (lg lg n)^(lg lg n) < n
<=>   lg ( (lg lg n)^(lg lg n) ) < lg n
 =>   lg ( (lg lg n)^(lg lg n) ) = (lg lg n) * (lg lg lg n) 
                                 < sqrt(lg n) * sqrt(lg n)
                                 = lg n
```

All in all you get

```
ceil(lg lg n)! < (1 + lg lg n) * (lg n) * n
```

without using landau-notation.

To your question (proving `theta(lg n)=o(n)`):
`f` in `o(g)` means `lim f(n)/g(n) -> 0` for `n` -> infinity. Due to `lim (lg n)/n -> 0`, `lg n` is in `o(n)`.
`e in Theta(f)` means `0 < liminf e(n)/f(n) <= limsup e(n)/f(n) < infinity`.
So `e` in `Theta(f)` has a upper bound by `c* f(n)`, for a constant number `c`.

So you get `e` in `Theta(lg n)` is bounded by `c * lg n` and due to `lim c lg n / n -> 0`, `e` is also in `o(n)`.